# XCUI setUpWithError not waiting for async functions to finish executing

Tags: swift, asynchronous, xctest, xcuitest, xcuiautomation

I have a `setUpWithError` function that I want to use to prevent duplicating code in each of the test's setup.

I have a couple of asynchronous functions that I want to run, prior to running some synchronous functions.

So far, I have this:

```
override func setUpWithError() throws {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Setup")

    Task {
        await function1()
        await function2()
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: defaultTimeout)
    
    synchronousFunction()
}
```

The expectation within the task doesn't appear to "wait" before the `synchronousFunction()` is called.

How can I resolve this please? Many thanks.

Comment: You should watch “Meet async await”  expectations aren’t needed with the new concurrency

Comment: When I don't use expectations, as shown in that video:

    `override func setUp() async throws {
        XCTAssertNoThrow(try await function1())
    }`

Returns `'async' call in an autoclosure that does not support concurrency`.

Comment: That means you haven’t added the “async” keyword, just add it to the signature like the example.

Comment: So I have `async` within the override setUp function, and the actual function I'm calling is `async` - `func function1() async { await doSomething()}`.

Does it need adding somewhere else?

Comment: The setup function just like the code you put in the comment above

Comment: There already is - `override func setUp() async throws...`

Comment: That is the one you need to use

Comment: Yes, which is returning the above error that I mentioned `'async' call in an autoclosure that does not support concurrency`

Comment: We can’t help with what we can’t see or reproduce

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different `setUp` method if you want to execute async code there.

You need to override `func setUp() async throws`. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctest/3856481-setup) for more information.

Comment: I believe I was seeing the same issue with the `async throws..` equivalent. I will revisit this, thank you.